# How to let requests print out raw HTTP requests sent without modifying the program?

Tags: python, logging, python-requests

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I currently add the following two lines to a python program using `requests` so that the raw HTTP requests can be printed. But I don't want to modify the program if possible.

Is there a way to let `requests` print the raw HTTP requests without modifying the program (possibly by environment variables?), yet still print out the raw HTTP requests sent?

Comment: "to let requests print the raw HTTP requests" - what exactly do you mean with "raw HTTP requests" ? The headers ? And how would you change your code to have them printed if you didn't want to not modify your code ?

Comment: As long as it can print as if logging.DEBUG is enabled, it's fine. Basically, users who see the message should be able to recreate the HTTP request manually.

Comment: Wait, do you mean you want the program to behave as if `import logging; 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` were added to the code, but without adding it ?

Comment: "without adding it" -> "without modifying the original program". If there is some way to enable `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` without modifying the original program, it should be fine.